# Are HTML entities considered a form of cryptography?

Tags: encoding

For example,
I could use these html entities to encode purchase data,

```
<a href="&#x23;"><input type="&#x62;&#x75;&#x74;&#x74;&#x6F;&#x6E;" value="&#x50;&#x75;&#x72;&#x63;&#x68;&#x61;&#x73;&#x65;"></a>
```

Instead of this decoded html

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1"><input type="button" value="Purchase"></a>
```

Comment: Ask this question to yourself: are they invented for cryptographic purposes at all?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is an **encoding**.

The mapping from HTML entities to letters is public, so this does *not* constitute encryption.

Comment: Encoding can easily be distinguished from encryption: if it doesn't use a key its encoding, if it does it could be encryption (it could also be keyed hashing etc.). There are some insecure in-betweens: ROT-13 can be thought of as the classical Caesar cipher with the key embedded in the algorithm name.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: That's actually encryption with the key [published by the W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref); therefore that's public key encryption, with the private key the rationale :-)